# Prove that for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n|x|<2^n$

Tags: real-analysis

How can we prove using Archimedes that for all  $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n|x|<2^n$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If the proposition is **false**, then there is necessarily some integer $x$ such that $2^n\le n|x|$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Equivalently, $|x|$ is an upper bound on the function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$ defined by $f(n)=\frac{2^n}{n}$.

Now, you should show that for every $m\in\Bbb N$ there is some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $m\leq f(n)$, from which it will follow that $|x|$ would be an upper bound of $\Bbb N$. This is, of course, impossible by the Archimedean Property of the Reals. Hence the Proposition holds.

---

You should consider the following result, related to the (now deleted) answer from Shu Xiao Li. You can use it to get almost all the way to the result I suggested that you prove.

**Lemma**: For any positive integer $m\neq3$, we have $m^2\le2^m$.

**Proof**: This is simply a matter of verification for $m=1,2,4,5$, and when $m=5$, the inequality is strict.

If for some $m>4$ we have $m^2<2^m$, then $$\begin{align}(m+1)^2 &= m^2+2m+1\\ &< m^2+4m\\ &< 2m^2\\ &<2\cdot 2^m\\ &= 2^{m+1},\end{align}$$ so the Lemma holds by induction on $m$. $\Box$

---

It isn't really necessary to use the Archimedean Property for this result, as we can simply proceed by (eventual) induction on $|x|$ using the Lemma, since $x$ is an integer. If we allow $x$ to be an arbitrary real number, then the Archimedean Property becomes a great deal more convenient, and we can proceed as I outlined above.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @Peter: I couldn't say. Take a look at my first version. That was the one that received the downvote. Perhaps you'll see something that I didn't.